# How to initialize multiple times the same Component with different dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, openapi-generator

I am currently have a spring service consuming an REST service via autogenerated code.
I placed an internal interface to have an abstraction from the REST interface since it is still in development.

The REST service is in fact two on the same host.
So I generate two times code having two components I can inject into my internal interface implementation.

In the interface implementation I do adapt the base paths of the REST client components via @PostConstruct since the URL is dependent on the deployment environment.

This works so far so good. Even though I believe it would be better to adapt the base path not in the internal interface implementation but instead in another place.
Thankful for any hints here.

### The Problem

Now the tricky part.
The REST Services I consume exists multiple times with different data in the environment.
Some times there are two, some times three and so on.
The user of our website should be able to select which backend he wants to consume.
The information about which service backends are available should be configurable for the environment.

To be able to configure these environment dependent I would thought about adding a map in the properties like:

- service-name: url
- second-name: url

and so on.
This map would  contain a default with the always existing service.
Via environment variables it can be overwritten to list more backend services.

So, now I want to be able to route the website request to the chosen backend service.
My idea is, that I would need some kind of service.
The service holds the internal interfaces with the different backend instances and can identify which to use based on the name.

The question is now, how to build this with Spring?
More specifically:

- How do I construct multiple time my InternalRestClient with different dependencies?
- How can I tell them apart/Identify and use them?

Thank you very much for your suggestions in advance.

### Code Examples

#### The internal Rest Interface

```java
public interface InternalRestClient {

    String someAbstractMethodUsingBothServices(String someDate);
}
```

#### The Implementation

```java
@Service
public class InternalRestClientImpl implements InternalRestClient{

    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;

    private FirstRestService firstService;
    private SecondRestService secondService;

    public InternalRestClientImpl(FirstRestService firstService, SecondRestService secondService) {
        this.firstService = firstService;
        this.secondService = secondService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void correctPaths() {
        firstService.setBasePath(url);
        secondService.setBasePath(url);
    }

    @Override
    public String someAbstractMethodUsingBothServices(String someDate) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### The autogenerated openapi components

```java
@Component
public class FirstRestService {

    private String basePath;

    public void setBasePath(String basePath) {
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }

    // some methods

}

@Component
public class SecondRestService {

    private String basePath;

    public void setBasePath(String basePath) {
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }

    // some other methods

}
```